# Accessing JSON Attributes of Tweet using Twitter API

Tags: python, json, twitter

This is a pretty basic question, but regardless its had me stumped for a bit. I'm trying to access a specific attribute of a tweet (documentation found [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.html)), such as "text". I tried accessing it via data["text"], however this gives me the following error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

So I tried parsing the data using `json.loads(data)` thinking this would allow me to access each attribute of the tweet. However this instead returns solely the text portion of the tweet, meaning when I do `print(newData)`, it prints out the text. Although this is useful, I need to be able to access other attributes of the tweet such as `"created_at"`.

So my **question** is, how do I parse the tweet or access it which allows me to pluck out individual attributes I need. To reiterate, I'm sure this is pretty simple, however I'm new to handling JSON objects, and other solutions I found simply told me to use loads(), which isn't what I want.

```
    class TwitterStreamer():
    """
    Class for streaming and processing live tweets for a given list of hashtags
    """
    def stream_tweets(selfself, hashtag_list):
        listener = StdOutListener()
        auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

        stream = Stream(auth, listener)

        stream.filter(track=hashtag_list)


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        newData = json.loads(data)
        print(newData["text"])
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


def main():
    hashtag_list = ['Chelsea']
    fetched_tweets_filename = "tweets.json"
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
    twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(hashtag_list)

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "." operator to access attributes of the tweet. I used it in my code as follow:

```
tweet = follow_user.status.created_at
```

In this I got the user in the form of JSON data **"status"** is an attribute of that JSON object **"follow_user"**

Comment: so in my example should it be `newData.status.text`? I tried this and it gives me the following error `'dict' object has no attribute 'status'`

Comment: Break that down into two lines:

**my_status = newData.status
answer = my_status.text**

OR
**my_status = newData['status']
answer = my_status['text']**

One of the above mentioned method will surely work. I have been using it since long but don't know the reason behind it actually
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try using json.load() to load the JSON as a Python object. The method json.loads() load the JSON as a string, that's why it gives you a TypeError Exception since string objects indices can only be integers.

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to use load() it gives me the following error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`, I read this is due to the fact that `json.load()` expects a file to be input to it? Hence why I decided to choose `loads()` over the `load()` method

Comment: You should use a context manager to read the file and easily iterate thorugh the JSON file after loading it using json.load().                                                         
 With open('tweets.json') as f:
       data = json.load(f)